# How to test website on other browsers and fix issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I have just completed a new Shopify website and used mainly Mozilla Firefox to put this together. I have been told by the client that the site doesn't show up properly in Chrome and Safari but when I have checked this on my 13" laptop they both appear fine on there and I was just wondering if anyone can give me any tips on how I can ensure that the site is working on all common browsers without having any issues.

Would appreciate any tips as I know there are paid websites to do this but just wondering if there is anything else that I can do to get this fixed.

Comment: Maybe download, install and run Chrome to see how it looks?

Comment: LGSon, thanks for your response. I already have Chrome and Safari on my laptop and the site shows up fine on both browsers..

Comment: Then the most common that comes to mind is to not have prefixed CSS properties properly, as some users still runs older versions of those browsers ... might be a good idea asking the ones telling it's not working which version they use

Comment: check on these sites listed in the article http://1stwebdesigner.com/cross-browser-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

If you to the safari developers "dropdown" in the status bar the is an option called "User agent" (the second one) from there you can "change" the browser.

Disclaimer: never actually used this function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best way to handle this would be to download and install all browsers to test.

There is a free service from the Microsoft dev site that gives you screenshots from a couple of different browsers and versions. Here is the link -> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/screenshots/

It's not as good as installing all browsers to fully test everything but it can give you a rough idea if there's something wrong with css or something like that.

Your issue might be related to different browser versions. Double check to make sure that you are on the same version to see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your tips